# How to call a simple MATLAB function in a MATLAB generated DLL from C#

Tags: c#, matlab, api, dll

Having problems building a DLL from MATLAB and calling its functions from C#

Here's the MATLAB function

```
function [success_code] = ENGINE_PING()
  success_code = 42;  
end
```

Here's the generated C++ header

```
extern LIB_ENGINE_C_API  
bool MW_CALL_CONV mlxENGINE_PING(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, mxArray *prhs[]);
```

My question is in two parts: what is the PInvoke declaration I should use? and How can I marshall values for passing and returning values?

I've reduced this to as simple an example as I can think of - I cannot use the MATLAB .NET Builder etc for licencing reasons.

I would very much appreciate some help with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1st part:

```
[DllImport(@"mclmcrrt7_17.dll", EntryPoint = "mclInitializeApplication_proxy", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern bool mclInitializeApplication(string options, Int32 count);
[DllImport(@"mclmcrrt7_17.dll", EntryPoint = "mclTerminateApplication_proxy", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void mclTerminateApplication();  
[DllImport("libmcc.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern bool _mlfCreat_smallsample (int nargout, ref IntPtr sample);
```

2rd part:(it is better to be wrapped in a function)

```
IntPtr num_ptr = MxCreateDoubleScalar((double)number);
IntPtr return_ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
double[] ans = new double[1];
_mlfFcn_add(1, ref return_ptr, sample, num_ptr);
Marshal.Copy(MxGetPr(return_ptr), ans, 0, 1);
return ans[0].ToString();

[DllImport(@"libmx.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
rivate static extern IntPtr mxGetPr([In]IntPtr mxArray);
```